# 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs - react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run the android build on my project with `yarn android` or through Android Studio and I am getting this error:

```
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:
 - /Users/MJ/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/52dc46a592dc383805ce46fda8bdc1a4/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.70.1-debug/jni/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so
 - /Users/MJ/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fdbc7f140d88eddac6969e3c2b95c806/transformed/jetified-common-23.0.0/jni/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so
If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets
```

I'm not too sure how this started showing up as the project was working at some point, but now the build will not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Need more information, packages, versions. In my case I have this same error, I've been searching all day but I can't get anywhere. I have only been able to deduce that it may be something related to react-native-vision-camera.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's because of this: [[FIXED] Android build failures](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

In my case I got exactly the same error as yours, since searching the internet, I found other similar ones but not the same one, nor did their solution work for me.

I upgraded from `react-native@0.68.4` to version `0.68.5` and it fixed it. In your case you must update to the latest corresponding version, if you have `0.63.x` -> `0.63.5`, `0.64.x` -> `0.64.4`, `0.65.x` -> `0.65.3`, `0.66.x` -> `0.66.5`, etc. **Check the issue.**